# Getting "Error Access Denied" with MobileFirst Platform v7.1 accessing JavaScript adapter from desktopbrowser environment

Tags: javascript, web, adapter, environment, ibm-mobilefirst

In my MobileFirst Platform Foundation v7.1 app, within MFPF Studio, I have a JavaScript adapter that deploys cleanly and can be invoked and works with a GET and 2 string parameters just fine when tested.  I have an iPhone environment that works perfectly with the adapter in the MobileBrowserSimulator.

However, I need to deploy this to a remote server.  After reading another posting here that the iPhone environment cannot be previewed in a browser on a remote server I followed the suggestion to create a desktopbrowser environment which is supposed to work on a remote server with a browser.  To test it I tried to run it on my local MFPF development server.  It fails.  The only error message is shown on the web page itself: Error  Access Denied.  (And a Reload button.)  Yet this still works fine previewing the iPhone environment in the MBS.

I tried clearing my browser cookies like another person did for a similar error, and I even tried a separate browser not previously used for this.  Neither worked.  It appears just the access to the adapter is being prevented.  Looking at the log in the browser I see the adapter being called with a POST as expected.  There seems to be some mismatch but the iPhone environment in the MBS works just fine (with a POST).  Please, how do I overcome this error?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1 is set to operate in a session-independent mode, which the Desktop Browser environment does not support. See more here: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_overview_session_indep.html

To use the Desktop Browser environment you need to set the server to not-work in session-independent mode. Sounds like this is not an option.

I suggest to use the iOS Simulator for your testing when not in the development environment.

Comment: Idan, thanks for the quick reply.  I think I have a problem, then.  I've installed MFPF Server v7.1 on a remote Linux on z Systems machine that is currently unreachable except by using double VPNs.  I can also reach it with VNC, which is why I wanted to test this in the browser.  I definitely can't reach it with a mobile device yet.

So according to the very good page you pointed me to, I think I will have to first build my project with MFPF v6.3, then import it into v7.1 and hope that the session-dependent behavior is retained so I can test it at all.  Thx.